# jQuery Vertical Marquee

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, marquee

I'm looking for a continuous scrolling marquee (not the HTML element!) which is similar to **[this one](http://www.homeessentials.co.uk/shop/?cm_re=FPS%20Homepage-_-S7-_-Home%20Essentials&)**, but instead scrolls vertically down.

With a lot of scrolling div's I've seen, these will reach the bottom, and then have to fully slide off the page, before the start is visible again. I need this to be continuous, so that the last logo in my div has the first logo directly beneath it.

Is there a jQuery plugin already available for this sort of animation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's a couple of jQuery add-ons that attempt to mimic the marquee affect. I've used this one before: http://www.vegabit.com/jquery_scroller/

It handles images / text etc so should enable you to do a vertical version of the marquee on the link you posted.

Edit: you do seem to have a fair problem with that plugin -

My alternative would be to use a simple animate loop. Never wanting to be defeated, here's one I made earlier! http://jsfiddle.net/gkTWC/48/ :)

And one for varying heights! http://jsfiddle.net/gkTWC/53/

Comment: Thats perfect timbo. I think this should help curt. +1 for nice answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I don't think this is going to work quite right. I need the logos to scroll up, and then once theyve reached the bottom, the top logo should appear beneath the bottom logo and continue looping. I think with this example they will all have to scroll out of view before the top one is shown again.

Comment: Hi @Curt, if you take the vertical_scroller example on the example page, you can basically create two "scrollingtext" divs within the vertical scroller, and repeat your content. You'll need to do a couple of sums to make sure they flow correctly but it will be possible to have your second copy following your first copy up, and vice versa.

Comment: But then what happens after the second content? Surely it'll be the same, it'll just look like every 2 loops there is a big gap instead of every 1?

Comment: Having had a play that does seem like more trouble than it's worth with that plugin...sorry!

Comment: No worries thanks anyway! Do you know of any other plugins available?

Comment: Cheers for putting in the effort to create this! Brilliant Job! Only thing is, each of my items will have a varying height :/ Is there anyway of modifying the scripts for this purpose?

Comment: No worries - I like a challenge on a friday PM! (See edit) :)

Comment: You can just simply put `:first` to `:last` (or vice versa, depending on markup and method used). This way every time the scroller moves down one, the first one is moved to directly behind the last one.

Comment: @rickyduck - Hi, I'm not sure that works as you're not actually changing the mark-up, we're just using a class hack to track which one is last in the animation order?

Comment: @Timbo , I see. If it works, it works :) Regarding the automated height, will be a bit more difficult, but certainly doable